# Multi Threading C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

So I am trying to implement multi-threading in my windows forms project. I know of one way to do this, by creating a new thread for the methods you want to run separately like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(methodName));
t.Start();
```

And then invoking each object that is "Accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." like this:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
{
this.Object = "whatever";
 }));
```

The only problem with this is, my program is several thousand lines long, and I make the references all the time. So putting a method invoker around every little thing I want to change in another thread seems horribly inefficient and Im sure there is a better way but I cant seem to find it online so I figured why not ask you guys.

Is there something I can say at the beginning of the method that will automatically delegate objects if they are referenced outside the thread? Because if there isnt another way, my code is probably going to turn out real messy and hard to read. :(

Edit: Here is a larger chunk of the code, maybe it will make this a bit clearer:

```
foreach (var lines in serversToRunTextBox.Lines)
{
    manipulationTextBox.Text = lines;
    string line = manipulationTextBox.Text;
    string scriptWithWild = actualScriptTextBox.Text.Replace(wildCard.ToString(), line);
    shellStream.WriteLine(scriptWithWild);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    client.RunCommand(scriptWithWild);
    //MessageBox.Show(scriptWithWild);
    Thread.Sleep(2500);

    reply = shellStream.Read();
    if (reply.Contains("denied"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must have sudo access for this command", "No Sudo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
    }
    else
    {
       this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
       {
           actualResultsTextBox.AppendText(reply + "\n \n");
       }));
```

Comment: No there's no way around it other than to architect your code in the most-efficient way possible.

Comment: Why do you need to execute this `this.Object = "whatever";` in UI thread? I think you misunderstood. This doesn't seem to access controls, so no need to marshal the call to UI thread.

Comment: I just used that as a filler, a real example would be

this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
            {
               this.statusTextBox.Text = " Sample Text";
            }));

Comment: Do not use `Thread` if you want to get results posted back to your UI. A `BackgroundWorker` may be more appropriate, but we cannot know for sure until you post your actual problem and not “filler”.

Comment: Ok, perhaps that doesnt make much sense. I need to be able to reference objects, and make changes to objects running in another thread. So il edit the post and show a larger chunk of code to show what I mean.

Comment: Can you please clarify what the exact question you're asking is? SO isn't really designed for explaining a concept as in-depth as how to design a multi-threaded Windows Forms application. For more information on asking questions on SO, please see [ask]. If your question is just `"Is there something I can say at the beginning of the method that will automatically delegate objects if they are referenced outside the thread?"` then the answer is that, no, there isn't.

Comment: If you have a lot of threads that produce results that need to end up on your GUI, you should probably try to limit the places where the code touches the actual GUI controls to one place (a 'controller' object of sorts, which could be the form itself) which exposes methods that do the necessary checking and invoking when necessary, then call those methods from your other threads, rather than directly accessing the GUI controls.

Comment: I dont know how to better explain this. And I thought that was excactly what this site was for; to get help with coding, along with its best practices?

Comment: Please post a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to deal with this is to leverage the async/await feature which was shipped with C# 5.0.

```
private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    //Some code
    string text = await GetSomeTextAsync(somrParam);
    statusTextBox.Text = text;//Will execute in captured context
    //Some more code
}
```

Code after the `await` keyword will execute in the captured context. So if you've called the `DoSomethingAsync` in UI thread, `statusTextBox.Text = text;` will execute in UI thread itself. So you don't need to call `this.Invoke`. And the result is "No more ugly code!!".

If you're not familiar with async/await [you can start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) and [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)